# Cause an async postback when a listbox is double-clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have an ASP.NET listbox, `lstActivities`. To edit an item in the list, users can either click `lnkButton` or double-click on the listbox. I achieve this with:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (IsPostBack) return;
  var refDblClick = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(lnkButton, "dblClick");
  lstActivities.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", refDblClick);
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
  ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(lnkButton.UniqueID, "dblClick");
  base.Render(writer);
}
```

I would like to change this so that the postback is asynchronous, using AJAX. At the moment, the listbox and button are in an UpdatePanel so there is an async postback when the button is clicked. But when the listbox is double-clicked, a full postback occurs.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"
 runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:ListBox ID="lstActivities" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButton" runat="server" OnClick="lnkButton_Click">
     Edit</asp:LinkButton>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

How can I make the double-click refresh only the UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the solutions suggested, but with no luck. It's quite a complicated page with lots of UpdatePanels so hard to work out the exact problem.

In the end I went for jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).delegate('#ctl00_body_lstActivities', 'dblclick', function () {
    eval($('#ctl00_body_lnkButton').attr('href'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things to try:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"
 runat="server">
   <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lstActivities" />
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkButton" />
   </Triggers>
   .........
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

or

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (IsPostBack) return;
  var refDblClick = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(lnkButton, "dblClick");
  lstActivities.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", refDblClick);

  ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lstActivities);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just a ran a quick test with the code you provided and I do get "partial postbacks" (for lack of a better term since updatepanels always do full postbacks) on both, the clicking of the button and the double clicking of the list.

If you set other panels in that page to `UpdateMode="Conditional"` as you are doing with your UpdatePanel "up", then only elements inside "up" will be updated. If you don't specify the update mode on the other panels, then they will always be updated on postback, because, again, update panels ALWAYS do full postbacks; what they really do is partial refreshes of the page.

Linking [MSDN documentation regarding UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx) as I think is a very helpful read.